# Getting error while using ReactNative + Redux-persist V 5.10

Tags: react-native, redux-persist

Getting error while using ReactNative + Redux-persist 5.10 - console.error: "redux-persist: rehydrate for "root" called after timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it to work by downgrading the redux-persist version from 5.10.0 to 5.6.12.

Answer (score 6):

No need to downgrade to any version. This just when you are in debugger mode and this is mostly related to issue with setTimeout in React Native [facebook/react-native#4470](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4470)

Answer (score 0):

Before downgrading anything, I will recommend you close your react-native debugger and try again. react-native debugger usually causes this error.

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes:

**1 - Emulator's date/time does not match your host OS  date/time.**

If that's the case, try to sync them

For example in Android you can go to(*)  *Settings / System / Date & Time* and make sure "**Use network-provided time**" is enabled.

If the date/time is still incorrect you might need to disable the previous setting, then turn Android off with the power button of the emulator (do not close the emulator), and enable the setting again.

(*) it may be different dependending on the Android version

**2 - redux-persist timeout is too short**

You can play with different timeout values and see what happens, for example:

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  timeout: 5000 // try with different values like 1000, 3000 or 5000
};
```